# How can I find the set of lowest parents (or ancestors) nodes of P1 that cut all paths between P1 and P2

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image]Suppose that I have the following graph. How can I find the lowest set of nodes that cut all (oriented) paths between nodes [1,2,3,4] and node [66]. In my case I want to find nodes [11, 5,9, 6] (node 7 must be excluded because node 6 and 9 are more lower ancestor to nodes 3 and 4. Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50574575/92359).

Here are the steps I would take:

1. Match to the starting nodes [1,2,3,4] and collect them for later.
2. Match to and expand out from your end node (66) to all connected nodes (using the directed pattern), blacklisting the starting nodes from step 1 (so we don't include paths to those nodes or beyond them). Collect these nodes as descendents.
3. Expand from your starting nodes, terminating at descendents (so we get paths to the first descendent encountered, but don't continue expanding past any of them).

Cypher doesn't have great support for performing the termination during expansion behavior in step 3, so we need [path expander procs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#path-expander) from [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) for that.

Let's say that these are nodes of type :Node with `id` properties for the numeric values, with :PARENT relationships between them pointing toward parents/ancestors. Let's say we have an index on :Node(id) for quick lookup. Using APOC our query would look something like:

```
MATCH (n:Node)
WHERE n.id IN [1,2,3,4]
WITH collect(n) as startNodes
MATCH path = (end:Node {id:66})<-[:PARENT*]-(descendent)
WHERE none(node in nodes(path) WHERE node in startNodes)
WITH startNodes, end, collect(DISTINCT descendent) as descendents
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(startNodes, {terminatorNodes:descendents}) YIELD node as mostRecentDescendents
RETURN mostRecentDescendents
```

Comment: Thankyou. But in this cas it reatchs node 7 or not? And what about node 0? At the end I want a result composed by [11,5,6,9]

Comment: With your graph, the query I provided should return the nodes associated by ids 11,5,6,9 (it will not reach 7 because both 6 and 9 are reached first, and no expansion past them is performed). You can change the return to `RETURN collect(mostRecentDescendents.id)` if you want to return just the list of the ids of those nodes.